# Создание плавности движения блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Блок двигается мгновенно, нужно сделать его движение плавным.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

document.addEventListener("mousemove", mm);
document.addEventListener('mouseover', mo);
var border = 50;

function mm(e) {
  if (e.clientX > div.offsetLeft - border &&
    e.clientX < div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth + border &&
    e.clientY > div.offsetTop - border &&
    e.clientY < div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight + border
  ) {
    div.style.left = Math.random() *
      (window.innerWidth - 50) + 'px';
    div.style.top = Math.random() *
      (window.innerHeight - 50) + 'px';
  }
}

function mo(e) {
  if (e.target === div)
    div.innerText = +(div.innerText || 0) + 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего это сделать с Jquery.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/6h366n0h/

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

document.addEventListener("mousemove", mm);
document.addEventListener('mouseover', mo);
var border = 50;

function mm(e) {
  if (e.clientX > div.offsetLeft - border &&
    e.clientX < div.offsetLeft + div.offsetWidth + border &&
    e.clientY > div.offsetTop - border &&
    e.clientY < div.offsetTop + div.offsetHeight + border
  ) {
    var a = Math.random()*(window.innerWidth - 50);
    var b = Math.random()*(window.innerHeight - 50);
    $(div).animate({
    left: a + 'px',
    top: b + 'px'
    }) ;
    
  }
}

function mo(e) {
  if (e.target === div)
    div.innerText = +(div.innerText || 0) + 1;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ради одного метода стоит тащить целую библиотеку?

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko я бы все делал под JQ или ничего, но по видимому автор пока слабо знаком с языком, потому я предложил самый легкий вариант из тех наработок что уже есть.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить елементу с классом .div CSS свойство transition. К примеру:

transition: all 0.3s; 
top: 0;
left: 0;

будет анимировать изменение любого CSS свойства, включая top и left.

Тут можно подробнее почитать и посмотреть примеры: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp